# Correct certificate for signing application with WineBottler

Tags: macos, wine, code-signing-certificate

I use WineBottler to convert a Windows program I wrote, Mineways, for use on the Mac. This process works fine, except that the application is unsigned and so runs afoul of OS X's new tightening of Gatekeeper, which scares off users. I have not been able to figure out how to get the proper "Mac Developer:" certificate as an Apple developer.

Winebottler has the ability to sign applications made with it, see [this page](https://mike.kronenberg.org/winebottler-1-5-30-now-with-codesigning-support/). All I need to do is get a "Mac Developer" certificate. I registered as an Apple developer, paying my $99. However, I can't figure out how to get this particular certificate it wants me to provide. I was able to get a "Developer ID Application:" certificate, but that's evidently not the same thing. The "Mac Developer:" certificate looks to be something I need to get from Xcode, but I'm not using Xcode to build my application, I'm using WineBottler to make a Windows program run on Mac.

There is some other terse documentation at the WineBottler site, linking to pages on Apple's site about bundles and Gatekeeper, but it is of little help to me, a simple Windows programmer. The author of WineBottler has not responded to my emails asking for clarification. My goal is an exact explanation of what I need to do to get a "Mac Developer:" certificate for use with my Windows program in Winebottler.

My efforts so far are further documented [here](https://github.com/erich666/Mineways/issues/11).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to create and find the Codesigning ID with Xcode 7.3:

1. Start the program **XCode**
2. From the Xcode Menu select "Preferences"

[image]

3. Select the tab "Accounts"
4. From Apple IDs, select you Apple ID
5. From "Team" select "GIVENNAME SURNAME (Personal Team)"
6. Click "View Details..."

[image]

7. In the new Panel click "Create" to the right of "Mac Development"
8. Click "Done"
9. Start the program **Keychain Access**

[image]

10. select "login" from "Keychains"
11. select "Certificates" from "Category"
12. Look for a Certificate named `Mac Developer: YOURAPPLEID (XXXXXXXXXX)` or `Mac Developer: GIVENNAME SURNAME (XXXXXXXXXX)` => this is your signing identity you can use to sign your apps.
13. Note the exact name of the ID: `Mac Developer: YOURAPPLEID (XXXXXXXXXX)` and enter that name in WineBottlers "Codesign Identity" field.

To my knowledge you can create this signing identity without paying the $99 - at least it is still noted as "Free" in Xcode.

Hope that helps

Mike

Sidenote:

Codesigning is and was changing with nearly every release of OS X / macOS since it was required by Gatekeeper. It is being checked and tested as of this writing for the next 1.8.x Release of WineBottler especially for macOS Sierra.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I'll have to wait until WineBottler supports Sierra, as XCode (which I don't have on my Mac) needs at least 10.11.5 El Capitan, but I'm at 10.10.5. I can't find any El Capitan 10.11 update itself, Apple wants me to go to Sierra.

Comment: It didn't work. With you step by step, I put in exactly the right settings for the field with "Mac Developer: Eric Haines (A...Q)" but it said it would not be signed and gave this error message: "Users/erichaines/Documents/Mineways.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed". I tried debugging by looking at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html, but that spewed a long dump that meant nothing to me. My settings are here: http://www.realtimerendering.com/erich/minecraft/public/mineways/images/winebottler.png Any tips appreciated, k3erg!